# Getting dynamic $refs value in Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a vue application.
I have dynamic `ref` binding for input elements that accept quantity
Something like this -

```
:ref="'qty' + index"
```

When I log `this.$refs`, I get all the refs. qty0, qty1, qty2 and so on.

My question is, how do I get the value of a particular input element using the ref?

I cannot hardcode `this.$refs.qty0` as the index keeps changing.

I tried

```
let quantityRef = 'qty' + index;
console.log(index); // 0
console.log(quantityRef); // qty0
console.log(this.$refs.quantityRef); // undefined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to find the doc. Just sharing this back for others.
[components-edge-cases](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a string key directly, with brackets:

```
this.$refs['qty' + index]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Why doesn't the dot syntax work though?

Comment: Dot syntax only works with static keys. Dynamic keys always require strings.

Comment: @JosephSilber that's true, I can't access the dynamic ref with variable over that syntax. :(

 this.$refs['slidesref'+ last]